# Can't log in after updating User model details in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have a user model that extended from AbstractBaseUser I've shown that below

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=80, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    # def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    #     return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Also, I need to update the User's details by using the view mentioned below

```
class UpdateUser(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializerAPI
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

After Changing user model details I can not log in. I'm using rest-auth login URL to log user in. When I try to log in it gives me an error saying

{
"non_field_errors": [
"Unable to log in with provided credentials."
]
}

What is the reason for that

Comment: did you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to your custom `User` model ? # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: yes I already did that

Comment: `After Changing user model details` What did you change? And can you double check your values in the database? According to `USERNAME_FIELD`, you're using the `email` as username, so be sure to log in with that.

Comment: I checked the database So I found my password is not encrypting after updating the user model. I wrote a perform_update method inside update view

Answer (score 0):

```
class UpdateUser(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializerAPI
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        instance = serializer.save()
        instance.set_password(instance.password)
        instance.save()
```

That's how I solved the problem